# Set a column color on a TableLayout

Tags: android, colors, background, tablelayout

I can set a row color on a tablelayout. What I need is to set a column to a specific color. My table cells are filled with textviews, I've tried setting the background on the textviews, but my textviews have padding and the padding seems to be transparent and not pickup the textview background color.

So, if its possible to set a column color that would be the best solution, an alternative would be to get the text view padding to be the same color as the textview itself.

The solution will need to be workable on the 2.1 OS version.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: "I've tried setting the background on the textviews, but my textviews have padding and the padding seems to be transparent and not pickup the textview background color." -- really? Margins are considered outside the background, but padding is inside, so I would expect this to work. Could you perhaps post some layouts or code?

Comment: Ok, sometimes its just good to recheck your work ). As I was copying code to paste in this question I saw that I was setting the padding in all the columns but the one I was trying to color. You are correct, once I set the padding on the textviews in the first column the color expanded to fill the cell. Thanks!

Comment: Whew! You had me scared there for a minute. Well, for a second or two, anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloring the Views in the column you want colored achieves the effect.